# Can't add any countries to Google Playstore Production release (WearOS)

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, google-play-console

I have everything filled out in the Dashboard 11/12 except the last one, which is adding Countries/Regions.

When I click on the Manage production countries/regions, nothing happens.

I've tried clearing cookies, restarting the browser, and relogging in.

[image]

[image]

How do I add countries to the Production track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out after an hour...

For a standalone WearOS app you cannot add countries with `Wear OS only` selected

[image]

You have to add the countries with `Phones, Tablets, Chrome OS` selected, even if you are publishing a standalone WearOS app to the playstore.

[image]

You don't have to create a release in the `Phones, Tablets, Chrome OS` section or fill anything else out except the countries section. This will then allow you to use those countries selected to publish a release to WearOS only.